htaccess SetEnvIfNoCase referrer does not block bad words
htaccess SetEnvIfNoCase referrer does not block bad words
bad referrer gave a link as "http". that's why the codes do not work. but https also works.
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ".*(poker|sevastopol|semalt|best|o-o-6-o-o|linkwebdirectory).*" bad_referer
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "\.pw" bad_referer
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Acunetix" bad_referer
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "FHscan" bad_referer
Deny from env=bad_referer

He gave the referer link as "http". That's why the codes don't work
My site has a htaccess https redirect.
sample: http://example. -- codes don't work
https://example. -- also works.
please help.
I need help: sample code http and https

"My site has a htaccess https redirect." - okay, but what does that have to do with the referrer? Really quite unclear what you are asking here.
